# Remove a property from object when value is "" Angular 6

Tags: data-binding, angular6, angular7, angular-ngmodel

```
Remove the property name "referenceNumber" from object "searchParams" when value of "referenceNumber" is "" (empty)


<input #refNumInput  (keyup)="onRefNumKeyUp($event)" [(ngModel)]="searchParams.referenceNumber" type="text" id="referenceNo" name="referenceNo">
```

Please refer the above code

Comment: You haven't provided enough information to make this question reasonably answerable here.  Read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: if(searchParams.referenceNumber == ""){
   delete searchParams.referenceNumber;
}

Comment: My code


            
    <input #refNumInput  (keyup)="onRefNumKeyUp($event)" [(ngModel)]="searchParams.referenceNumber" type="text" id="referenceNo" name="referenceNo">
    
    
    
    
        I need to remove the property  name "referenceNumber" from object called "searchParams" when value of "referenceNumber" is empty. Here this property is added by Angular when I type in the "input" tag. Below is the code snippet